# Run-time error '1004' The extract range has a missing or invalid field name

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, field-names

```
.Range("A2:Q" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=.Range("s2:s3"), CopyToRange:=.Range("AA2:AJ2"), Unique:=True
```

Who can help me out?

I've been trying to figure it out, but can not fix it.

This is the code:

Sub InventoryAdj_LoadItems()

With InvWkSht
If .Range("b2").Value = True Then
If MsgBox("Changes have been made to this adjustment. Are you sure you wnat to clear these changes without saving?", vbYesNo, "Changes Not Saved") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
.Range("A7:O9999").ClearContents 'Clear All existing data
'Remove Existing Pictures
For Each PicShp In .Shapes
If InStr(PicShp.Name, "ItemPic") > 0 Then PicShp.Delete 'Delete picture shape
Next PicShp
SortCol = .Range("B1").Value 'Set Sort Column
End With

With Items
LastRow = .Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row
If LastRow < 3 Then GoTo Nodata
.Range("A2:Q" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=.Range("s2:s3"), CopyToRange:=.Range("AA2:AJ2"), Unique:=True

```
LastResultRow = .Range("AA99999").End(xlUp).Row
If LastResultRow < 3 Then GoTo Nodata

    'Run Sort
    With .Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Items.Cells(3, SortCol), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal  'sort based on user entry
    .SetRange Items.Range("aa3:AJ" & LastResultRow)
    .Apply
    End With
```

InvWkSht.Range("a7:i" & LastResultRow + 4).Value = .Range("aa3:Ai" & LastResultRow).Value 'bring over item data
InvWkSht.Range("n7:n" & LastResultRow + 4).Value = .Range("aj3:AJ" & LastResultRow).Value 'bring over item DB row
End With
Nodata: Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Comment: Not much we can suggest without at least a couple of screenshots of your headers and of the criteria range?

Comment: Previously here: https://www.google.com/search?q=The+extract+range+has+a+missing+or+invalid+field+name+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Is this line inside a `with ... ` statement?

Comment: Yes it is a With statemtn.  Ill make some screenshots